# Combine one table with meta data in another table

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to get all result combined from two tables. Currently, I am making two requests to get a table, but I believe there are many good ways to combine the result. I've tried using `join` with this query

```
USE test;
SELECT * FROM main INNER JOIN main_meta ON main.id = main_meta.ref WHERE main.id = 1;
```

but ended up having repeating data like this:

| id | body | title | time | id | ref | data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | happy birthday to you ! | Birthday Celebration | 2021-10-14 06:34:36 | 1 | 1 | first_name: ABC |
| 1 | happy birthday to you ! | Birthday Celebration | 2021-10-14 06:34:36 | 2 | 1 | last_name: DEF |
| 1 | happy birthday to you ! | Birthday Celebration | 2021-10-14 06:34:36 | 3 | 1 | email: abc@xyz.co |

There is one main entry which will have any number of metadata for that reason main post is repeating multiple times now. I wanted to get main data once and multiple metadata in result.

The result I'm looking for is this:

| id | body | title | time | id | ref | data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | happy birthday to you ! | Birthday Celebration | 2021-10-14 06:34:36 | 1 | 1 | first_name: ABC |
|  |  |  |  | 2 | 1 | last_name: DEF |
|  |  |  |  | 3 | 1 | email: abc@xyz.co |

Comment: Please post you query and sample data in textual/tabular form. It's easier to _copy & paste_ if anyone wants to attempt what you're doing rather than re-write everything from images.

Comment: its just a simple line and no one can run wihout same data so i thought it will be not so usefull to provide used code anyways i have updated ans now

Comment: It is not required for the sample data to be your exact data. Fake data would suffice as long as it replicates your data. You can even just use `first_name: ABC, last_name: DEF, email: abc@xyz.com` in your sample data. As it is, your query doesn't seem to be wrong. When you said _"repeated data"_ are you referring to the result being returned with 3 rows? I don't assume you mean the `data` column because there's no repetition there (according to your screenshot). If the 3 rows of result is not what you're aiming for, what is your expected result? Please illustrate, thanks!

Comment: sorry for being not so expressive i am actually not familiar with all the things in mysql
i am just looking for any idea if that can format result in a way which will not return main data everytime for each meta data thats all i can tell

Comment: also i wanted to add that before posting my question i actuall saw some other posts where peoples are using `UNION` `SELECT (statement 1),(statement 2)` but i dont know about how these functions works

Comment: Let me try to edit your question and see if that's what you're aiming for. If not, please edit it according to your requirement.

Comment: you edited so well thanks for that

Comment: I assume it's what you trying to get yes? I'll post a couple of answer suggestions and see if you can use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind having `data` column with combined values, then you might want to consider using `GROUP_CONCAT()`. So a query like this:

```
SELECT main.id, main.body, main.title, main.time, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(main_meta.data)
    FROM main 
INNER JOIN main_meta 
ON main.id = main_meta.ref 
WHERE main.id = 1
GROUP BY id, body, title, time;
```

.. will return you result like this:

| id | body | title | time | GROUP_CONCAT(main_meta.data) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | happy birthday to you ! | Birthday Celebration | 2021-10-14 06:34:36 | first_name: ABC,last_name: DEF,email: abc@xyz.co |

If you want the `data` column values to be separated (like in your question edit), then this suggestion (works with MySQL v8+ or MariaDB v10.2+ and above):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN rn=1 THEN id ELSE '' END id,
       CASE WHEN rn=1 THEN body ELSE '' END body,
       CASE WHEN rn=1 THEN title ELSE '' END title,
       CASE WHEN rn=1 THEN time ELSE '' END time,
       data
 FROM
(SELECT main.id, main.body, main.title, main.time, main_meta.data, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY main.id ORDER BY main_meta.id) rn
    FROM main 
INNER JOIN main_meta 
ON main.id = main_meta.ref 
WHERE main.id = 1) v;
```

Although it is possible, I'm not sure if there's any reason to make it like that unless it's only for viewing purposes. And if the end result is going to be shown on a webpage (e.g. for web report view) then, it's better to do the second option in the application code rather than from the MySQL query.

Anyway, here's a [demo fiddle for reference](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5083b1f7325796d1d64441a2c20dc789)

Comment: first one is fitting good for now for second result i will have to research those syntaxes but that ans is so usefull also your edit was good thanks for your time and knowledge

Comment: Actually for the first option, you can add a line termination in `GROUP_CONCAT(main_meta.data SEPARATOR '\r\n')`  function that will make the results _row like_. You can see the [fiddle demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=09d490ac694932173a8827e3843dff71) how it looks like.

Comment: i have a question if i am grouping values is there any performance benefit compare to last when it was returning repeating data ?

Comment: I'm not really sure but it's hard to determine from a very small set of data. Probably if you have a very large data then we can measure. However, in general, if all of the columns used in the query is properly indexed, it will greatly benefit the performance. If you want to know more, you can read [Rick's rule of thumb](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/ricksrots) , it has helped me a lot in understanding mysql query performance and I hope it you can benefit from it too.